# Manage buttons in different XML files

Tags: android, android-layout

There are two xml files in my project,"main.xml" and "newn.xml". Button with id button1 in main.xml and button2 in newn.xml.

I would like to click the button1 and go to newn layout file and come back to main layout when I click button2.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.newn);
        }
    });
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    });
```

but there was a run time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply switch layouts in this manner.

If you want a new layout to show you need to use Fragments, dialogs, or start a new Activity.

Follow this tutorial to learn how to start a new activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html